# Defining your own explicit conversions

Tags: c++, type-conversion, explicit

Suppose, if a conversion from one type another type is not available through explicit casts e.g `static_cast`, Would it be possible to define explicit conversion operators for it?

**Edit**:

I'm looking for a way to define explicit conversion operators for the following:

```
class SmallInt {

public:

    // The Default Constructor
    SmallInt(int i = 0): val(i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > 255)
        throw std::out_of_range("Bad SmallInt initializer");
    }

    // Conversion Operator
    operator int() const {
        return val;
    }

private:
    std::size_t val;

};

int main()
{
     SmallInt si(100);

     int i = si; // here, I want an explicit conversion.
}
```

Comment: Explicit conversion operators would be, well, methods that return the target type.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For user defined types you can define a [type cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). The syntax for the operator is

```
operator <return-type>()
```

You should also know that implicit type cast operators are generally frowned upon because they might allow the compiler too much leeway and cause unexpected behavior. Instead you should define `to_someType()` member functions in your class to perform the type conversion.

---

Not sure about this, but I believe C++0x allows you to specify a type cast is `explicit` to prevent implicit type conversions.

Comment: @Toolbox which compilers have implemented this feature of C++11? I dont' think MSVC++ 2010 has.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie According to http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html, explicit conversion operators are available in GCC 4.5. I haven't been able to test this myself.

Answer (score 2):

In the current standard, conversions from your type to a different type cannot be marked `explicit`, which make sense up to some extent: if you want to explicitly convert you can always provide a function that implements the conversion:

```
struct small_int {
   int value();
};
small_int si(10);
int i = si.value();   // explicit in some sense, cannot be implicitly converted
```

Then again, it might not make *that* much sense, since in the upcoming standard, if your compiler supports it, you can tag the conversion operator as `explicit`:

```
struct small_int {
   explicit operator int();
};
small_int si(10);
// int i = si;                 // error
int i = (int)si;               // ok: explicit conversion
int j = static_cast<int>(si);  // ok: explicit conversion
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want, you can define conversion operators, e.g.:

```
void foo (bool b) {}

struct S {
   operator bool () {return true;} // convert to a bool
};

int main () {
   S s;
   foo (s);  // call the operator bool.
}
```

Although it is not really recommended because once defined, such implicit conversion can occur in awkward places where you don't expect it.

Comment: Yes, but can I turn this into accepting only explicit conversions?

Comment: I think so in C++0x, as the answer above says. Why don't you just define a `to_XXX` member function?